# unable to generate vulnerability audit report in maven

Tags: java, maven

getting below error when trying to use the below plugin in my pom

**Plugin:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.ossindex.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>ossindex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>audit-dependencies</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>audit</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <reportFile>D:/Maven_pheonixx/audit-report.txt</reportFile>
        </configuration>
     </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0:audit (audit-dependencies) on project ucs: Execution audit-dependencies of goal org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0:audit failed: Unable to load the mojo 'audit' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.sonatype.ossindex.maven.common.ComponentReportAssistant was bound.
[ERROR]   while locating org.sonatype.ossindex.maven.plugin.AuditMojo
[ERROR]   at ClassRealm[plugin>org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR]   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0:audit)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR]   roleHint: org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0:audit
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0:audit (audit-dependencies) on project ucs: Execution audit-dependencies of goal org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0:audit failed: Unable to load the mojo 'audit' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.2.0'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Kindly help me to fix this issue

Maven version : 3.6.2
JDK version : 1.8.0_333

Need to get vulnerability reports for the dependencies in the pom.

Comment: Can you do maven version from wherever you are running this command?  As well verify your java version as well.  Make sure you are checking in the place where you run.

As well, how are you running this plugin?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T20:36:16+05:30)
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_333, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: added the plugin in the pom.xml and executing mvn clean install

Comment: I would suggest you use a lower version, try maven 3.2 and see if that helps.

Comment: tried using maven 3.1 and 3.2.3, same error occurs